# How to fix cannot resolve symbol android studio

Tags: javascript, android, server, retrofit2

I'm extremely new to android development and have been pulling my hair out basically to try and fix this error i have been having when i attempt import retrofit2 for instance i get an error like (Cannot resolve symbol 'Retrofit')And i was hoping someone more experienced could help me

dependencies i have in my project] ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jdhC.png)
the error
[Some of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfG5B.png)
[more of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRgiv.png)

I've re synced my grade
restarted android studio
cleaned and rebuilt the project checked if i might have misspelled something i know that im missing something but i am not sure how to procede

Comment: Please don't post code in screen shots. Code is text so you can simply include it in your question.

Comment: Understood,thank you

Answer (score 0):

try using Alt + Enter to import. and try invalidating the caches and restart.
File > Invalidate Caches > check all boxes. then invalidate and restart. then. try to sync gradle before using it.

Comment: Thank you very much will give it an attempt